# polynomial equation standard ml

Tags: functional-programming, standards, eval, sml

I'm trying to make a function that will solve a univariante polynomial equation in Standard ML, but it keeps giving me error.

The code is below

```
(* Eval Function *)
- fun eval (x::xs, a:real):real = 
    let
        val v = x (* The first element, since its not multiplied by anything *)
        val count = 1 (* We start counting from the second element *)
    in
        v + elms(xs, a, count)
    end;

(* Helper Function*)
- fun pow (base:real, 0) = 1.0
    | pow (base:real, exp:int):real = base * pow(base, exp - 1);

(* A function that solves the equation except the last element in the equation, the constant *)
- fun elms (l:real list, a:real, count:int):real = 
    if (length l) = count then 0.0
    else ((hd l) * pow(a, count)) + elms((tl l), a, count + 1);
```

now the input should be the coefficient if the polynomial elements and a number to substitute the variable, ie if we have the function 3x^2 + 5x + 1, and we want to substitute x by 2, then we would call the eval as follows:

```
eval ([1.0, 5.0, 3.0], 2.0);
```

and the result should be 23.0, but sometimes on different input, its giving me different answers, but on this imput its giving me the following error

> uncaught exception Empty   raised at:
>   smlnj/init/pervasive.sml:209.19-209.24

what could be my problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some recursive calls, `elms` function gets empty list as its argument. Since `count` is always greater than 0, `(length l) = count` is always false and the calls `hd` and `tl` on empty list are failed right after that.

A good way to fix it is using pattern matching to handle empty lists on both `eval` and `elms`:

```
fun elms ([], _, _) = 0.0
  | elms (x::xs, a, count) = (x * pow(a, count)) + elms(xs, a, count + 1)

fun eval ([], _) = 0.0 
  | eval (x::xs, a) = x + elms(xs, a, 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

`Empty` is raised when you run `hd` or `tl` on an empty list. `hd` and `tl` are almost never used in ML; lists are almost always deconstructed using pattern matching instead; it's much prettier and safer. You don't seem to have a case for empty lists, and I didn't go through your code to figure out what you did, but you should be able to work it out yourself.